# Get name of the month

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```js
var d = new Date('2015-05-14T00:20:00.000Z');
var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };

console.log(d.toLocaleString(options));
```

I want to get the name of the month plus the rest of data like: May 14, 2010 3:20. Why i don't get what i want in my example? How to solve the issue?

Comment: @Rayon, that answer is not  what i want. In  their example they don't use this format: `2015-05-14T00:20:00.000Z`

Comment: I don't think that would affect the use case. As long as you are trying to retrieve the name of the month, that suffice the requirement.